# Why we call the set open or closed by only looking at one side?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a simple question, for example,

$$ A=(1, \infty),~~~~B=[2,\infty)$$

I know $,\infty)$ is both open and closed. But why we call $A$ open, instead of neither open nor closed?

Similarly, for $B$, we call it closed instead of neither open nor closed?

It seems whenever involve $\infty$, we only look at the other side (open/closed) to determine the whole set to be open/closed, why?

Comment: Remind us and yourself what the *definition* is of "open."  Perhaps something involving "balls."  See whether your set satisfies the definition.

Comment: [Open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set). Basically, an open set, with each point, contains an open "ball" around that point as well. Closed sets are not merely sets that are "not open": closed sets are *complements of open sets* - so $[2,\infty)$ is closed because it is a complement of $(-\infty, 2)$.

Comment: There are multiple definitions of open and closed. Here, you seem to be talking about open and closed ends of intervals. That is, technically, not the most common meaning.

Comment: I see, I got it, thank you @JMoravitz

Comment: Right, thank you! @StinkingBishop

Comment: I've seen references to "half-open" (or for pessimists, "half-closed") intervals.

Comment: Keep in mind: $\infty$ is not a number. So when $\infty$ occurs as a symbol representing an endpoint of an interval, you should be **expecting** different behavior than when an actual number occurs as an endpoint of an interval. For example, the bracketing symbol next to an $\infty$ endpoint of an interval is *always* a round bracket and *never* a square bracket, the simple reason being that a square bracket implies that the endpoint is a number but $\infty$ is not a number.

Comment: thank you, can you write an answer so that I can close this question? @LeeMosher

Answer (score 1):

**Turning my comment into an answer:**

Keep in mind: $\infty$ is not a number. So when $\infty$ occurs as a symbol representing an endpoint of an interval, you should be expecting different behavior than when an actual number occurs as an endpoint of an interval. For example, the bracketing symbol next to an $\infty$ endpoint of an interval is always a round bracket and never a square bracket, the simple reason being that a square bracket implies that the endpoint is a number, *but* $\infty$ is not a number.